# Can't read a file inside functions folder

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I have an expressjs app running on Firebase and from my `firebase-express/functions/index.js` I' am trying to read the file located at `functions/api/swagger/swagger.yaml`.

```
const swaggerDocument = YAML.load('./api/swagger/swagger.yaml');
```

When I run locally with `firebase serve`, I get the following error.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Tulio\Desktop\firebase-express\api\swagger\swagger.yaml'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:642:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:510:33)
    at Function.Utils.getStringFromFile (C:\Users\Tulio\Desktop\firebase-express\functions\node_modules\yamljs\lib\Utils.js:284:19)
    at Function.Yaml.parseFile (C:\Users\Tulio\Desktop\firebase-express\functions\node_modules\yamljs\lib\Yaml.js:46:21)
    at Function.Yaml.load (C:\Users\Tulio\Desktop\firebase-express\functions\node_modules\yamljs\lib\Yaml.js:78:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tulio\Desktop\firebase-express\functions\index.js:11:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
```

It is looking for the file at `'C:\Users\Tulio\Desktop\firebase-express\api\swagger\swagger.yaml'`, so the solution must be to change my parameter to include the folder 'functions' right?

```
const swaggerDocument = YAML.load('./functions/api/swagger/swagger.yaml');
```

Now I get another error where it shows the path as:

```
no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Tulio\Desktop\firebase-express\functions\functions\api\swagger\swagger.yaml'
```

Notice the **'functions\functions'**? For some reason when I add 'functions/' to the path, it appends another 'functions/', making the path invalid.

**How can I get the correct path for a file inside the `functions` folder?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **Path** library

```
var path = require('path');
var swagger_path =  path.resolve(__dirname,'./api/swagger/swagger.yaml');
console.log(swagger_path);
```

This will fetch the proper path in any environment.